# hitTest:withEvent: UIEvent allTouches is empty

Tags: ios, uiview, uitouch, uievent

I have a custom `UIView` that implements `hitTest:withEvent:`

```
-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    .... some code ....

    int x = 0;
    x = [[event allTouches] count];
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

The problem is that `x` is always `0`. Do I have implement other APIs or configure the `UIView` to start getting the touches?

I only needed it in order to differentiate between touch start/move and end.

Comment: What is shown by `NSLog(@"Event: %@", event);`?

Comment: Event: <UITouchesEvent: 0x6a1abc0> timestamp: 0 touches: {(
)}
Event: <UITouchesEvent: 0x6a1abc0> timestamp: 0 touches: {(
)}
Event: <UITouchesEvent: 0x6a1abc0> timestamp: 248999 touches: {(
)}

Comment: @PhillipMills hitTest gets called three times with the logs above

Comment: It worth mentioning that this custom UIView is used as a top level container\view in UIViewController. To use it, I only modified the xib file of the viewcontroller

Comment: Touches aren't added to the event until after hit testing succeeds. What is it that you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: "Touches aren't added to the event until after hit testing succeeds." Then why is the view getting the touch-type event in the first place? If you check event.type, it is UIEvent.EventType.touches

Answer (score -4):

Try this

```
yourView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

iOs provides the possibility to nullify the user interactions in the view hierarchies. Being said that in the chain of events on iOS it's possible to ignore the touch event in the most immediate view in the view stacks and then the next view in the hierarchy will try to take responsibility to respond to the interaction.

Being said all the previous it can be happening that the view that should respond to the user interaction is being set to NO, so the next view in the hierarchy will respond to the event. This can be the reason why it was not working for you.

Comment: Why?  Why should he try this?  Edit your answer to be more informative.